# A screen virtual LED on linux

Tags: linux, bash, notifications, led, ubuntu-unity

We have some LEDs on our machine to indicate the status of Caps Lock, Num Lock etc. Now I need a virtual LED in Linux to notify something.

For example, I wrote a script to monitor a website. When the website changes, my script will output some information. And I want to notify myself whenever the script output something. I know the program `notify-send` can do this. But `notify-send` may disturb me. I'd like to find a utility which works like a LED.

> **NOTE**: I am not finding a LED indicator of the real LED status. I want a LED analog utility so that I can change it's color/brightness on my screen/toolbar.

Say, the program name is `led`. When I start the program, there will be a icon in the toolbar with default color black. And I can use the following command to change the status of this `LED'

```
$ led red     #then the virtual LED change color to red
$ led blue    #change color to blue
$ led flicker #then the light flicker
```

And so on. The above description is just an example. But the basic idea is something like that. Can this be understood? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. Looks like it's very easy, I think you only need to write a shell script.

http://www.avrfreaks.net/wiki/index.php/Documentation:Linux/LEDs

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your suggestion seems like to be the `REAL LED`. What I want is a indicator utility but not a real LED. I've improved my question to be better understood now.